# how do i compute the result of a solidity contract without paying gas fee?

Tags: solidity

suppose I have this solidity contract, I would like to calculate the result of `minAmountOut2`, without actually paying the gas gas fee. Is it possible to achieve it? I think this should be theoretically possible, but I'm not sure how to achieve it practically.... Thanks!

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Storage {
    
    constructor()  payable {
        // uint256 number;
        address wbnb_addres = 0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c; 
        address pancake_swap_v2 = 0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E; 
        uint amount = msg.value ;
        address target_token_address = 0x0E09FaBB73Bd3Ade0a17ECC321fD13a19e81cE82;
        address sender_address = tx.origin;
        address[] memory address_input = new address[](2);
        address_input[0] = wbnb_addres;
        address_input[1] = target_token_address;

        uint[] memory result = IPancakeRouter02(pancake_swap_v2).getAmountsOut(amount,address_input);
        uint minAmountOut = result[1];
        uint deadline = 1e30;

        address[] memory address_output2 = new address[](2);
        address_output2[0] = target_token_address;
        address_output2[1] = wbnb_addres;

        uint[] memory result2 = IPancakeRouter02(pancake_swap_v2).getAmountsOut(minAmountOut,address_output2);
        uint minAmountOut2 = result2[1];

        


    }    

    

}
```

One possible way is that I convert the result into string and trigger a revert function.... Then when I run estimatgas function in web3, then i got the result using error and exception handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Far as I know [estimateGas](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4.0/web3-eth.html?highlight=estimateGas#estimategas) is the only such function. estimateGas should be almost  equal to [web3.eth.sendTransaction](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4.0/web3-eth.html?highlight=estimateGas#sendtransaction), the only difference between them is estimateGas does not send the transaction out actually, and if your operation will fail when call a function, you can not get a valid result by estimateGas.

You have now all code in constructor. You probably want to split the code up in smaller functions and then call estimateGas.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, is it possible to get `minAmountOut2` without paying the gas? estimate gas couldn't output value...

Comment: Changing state of blockchain costs gas but just querying the blockchain for it's current satate doesn't cost gas. Far as I understand you want to run .getAmountsOut() in order to get estimate of "token swap" result. .getAmountsOut() is a view so you can call it outside blockchain via Web3, for example, in python, javascript, and only try to change state of blockchain if you are satified with result from read function.

Comment: ok... so i am actually trying to simulate change of state without paying gas fee. Basically, I am trying to ask "if I interact with contracts (write), what would happen", without actually letting it happen....

Comment: Hi @Peteris, Does .getAmountsOut() consider all fees, gas/slippage, etc. For example if the contract has reflections are these taken in to account or would these need to be calculated after. So is .getAmountsOut() the estimated final value which will be returned to sender.